How does lattice reduction produce $s$ and $e$ from public parameters of an LWE instance?
It has been shown that by embedding $A$ and $t$ from an LWE instance $A$, $t=As+e$ inside a lattice, we can find a vector from the reduced lattice that contains $s$ and $e$.
For example, in the lattice below, I am able to get a vector containing $\begin{pmatrix}-e & s & -1\end{pmatrix}$.
$$
\mathbf{B} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
q I_m & 0 & 0 \\
A^T & I_n & 0 \\
t & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Is there a mathematical reasoning behind this?

Do you mean that $(-e, s, 1)$ appears as a basis vector in the reduced basis, or you are able to recover it using the reduced basis?

($-e,s,-1$) appears as a basis vector in the reduced basis.

What you're doing is standard/expected. The technical way of describing it is using Kannan's embedding to reduce LWE to uSVP, and then solving uSVP with lattice reduction.
You can read more about this many places, see for example the introduction of this paper for one concrete one. If you have particular questions about (the introduction of) this paper feel free to modify your question appropriately, otherwise I'll post this comment as an answer in a bit.

Thanks for the materials! What I am trying to understand is how the uSVP produces the vector (-e,s,-1) with this specific ordering of e and s?

Please have a quick look on the formatting of the vectors in the edited question and if it still displays alright. If you hit [edit] then you can also see the used MathJax / $\LaTeX$ input.

The span of the first $m+n$ rows of the matrix matrix $\mathbf B$ consists of all entries $(y_1, y_2,\ldots, y_m, x_1,\ldots,x _n,0)$ where $A\mathbf x\equiv\mathbf y \pmod q$ (we here write $\mathbf x$ for the $n$ long column vector with entries $x_i$ and $\mathbf y$ for the $m$ long column vector with entries $y_j$). Specifically, the span of the $(m+1)$th through $(m+n)$th rows represents solutions which hold over the integers and the span of 1st through $m$th rows represent the possible mod $q$ offsets.
In particular then the span of the first $m+n$ rows includes $((A\mathbf s)^T,\mathbf s^T,0)$. Looking at the span of all the rows of $\mathbf B$ it must include this vector subtract the final row i.e. $((A\mathbf s-\mathbf t)^T,\mathbf s^T,-1)=(-\mathbf e^T,\mathbf s^T, -1)$.
